# How to push UITableView without UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My app consists of the screens as shown in the attached image.

I added manually a UITableView object as a subview in the UIViewController, and I implemented the datasource and delegate for the UITableView A. It can display the data and react the touch events correctly.

I need to push one more level down when a row is touched in UITableView A.

However, since I am using a UITableViewController, how can I push the UITableView ?

Due to limitation, it is not allowed to push to another UIViewController from the current UIViewController.

I understand that it is quite complicated and confusing. I just want to switch from UITableView A to UITableView B.

Appreciate it if you can offer me a helping hand. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ankit Srivastava: everything is possible

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` create the same instance of the table view and push it from there with the dataSource updated for that specific row. If you need further assistance, let me know. I have done this before.

For example, if your table view controller is named `RootViewController`, your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method should look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[self.navigationController viewControllers] count] < 3) {
    RootViewController *detailViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    detailViewController.rootArray = [self.rootArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

and `numberOfRowsInSection` :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [rootArray count];
}
```

`rootArray` is an array containing the information you display in the current table view controller and is created from a master array prior created in the delegate or any other master class with access to your controller. Like this (created in the delegate in my example) :

```
NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
    NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"5", nil];
    NSArray *array3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"6", @"7", nil];
    NSArray *array4 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"8", @"9", nil];
    NSArray *array5 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10", @"11", @"12", nil];
    NSArray *array6 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"14", @"15", @"13", nil];
    NSArray *array7 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"16", @"17", nil];
    NSArray *array8 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"19", @"18", nil];
    NSArray *array9 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"20", @"21", @"22", nil];

    NSMutableArray *mutable1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:array1, array2, array3, nil];
    NSMutableArray *mutable2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:array4, array5, array6, nil];
    NSMutableArray *mutable3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:array7, array8, array9, nil];

    self.initialArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:mutable1, mutable2, mutable3, nil];
```

And the `viewDidLoad` for the current tableViewController, so you have an array for the first load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([[self.navigationController viewControllers] count] == 1) {
        self.rootArray = appDelegate.initialArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need your help. I know how to modify the datasource, but I do not know to push the UITableView. How can I contact you?

Comment: Hi, just added your contact in my Skype. Please accept my request. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a tableViewController? Maybe by having a tableViewController without affecting your view hierarchy? Use a tableViewController but add the tableview as a subview to your UIViewController's view - which is what I assume you are currently doing.

Or if you only want to switch them just add two tableviews and alternate their visibility?

Comment: I could not use UITableViewController, because the UITableView could not be resized and other UIViews are not allowed.